# Can we list down all order 4 integer valued 3 x 3 matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can we list down all integer 3 x 3 matrices($A$) whose are order 4  i.e  $A^4= I$? or atleast get some examples? What should be the method for such thing?

Answer (score 0):

To get some examples, you can just remember the $2 \times 2$ representation of $i$ as $\begin {pmatrix} 0&-1\\1&0 \end {pmatrix}$ which has fourth power $I$.  Now just add one more row/column that has a $1$ on the main diagonal somewhere.  Also all matrices of the form $\begin {pmatrix} \pm 1&0&0\\0& \pm 1&0\\0&0&\pm 1 \end {pmatrix}$ will qualify.  So will $I$ itself.

To try to find them all, you can write an arbitrary matrix with nine variables for entries, take it to the fourth power, equate it to $I$, and see where that leads.  In theory it is nine equations in nine unknowns, but there may well be dependencies there.